# Copy the RequestMessage at IParameterInspector.BeforeCall() on WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have WCF service with `IParameterInspector` class which suppose to store the message for each incoming message. I need to extract values from the inputs parameters.

In order to get the message I'm trying to access

> Blockquote
>   OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage
>   Blockquote

and than call to `CreateBufferedCopy()` method to create a copy so I can work (read) the message and send it forward, but than I'm getting the following error:
**"This message cannot support the operation because it has been read."**

Any ideas?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IParameterInspector` is fired *after* the message has been read by the data contract/xml serializer so the message body has been already consumed.

If you want to get the raw input message, you should be doing so in an `IDispatchMessageInspector` instead and make a [buffered copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.createbufferedcopy.aspx) of the message so that you can still pass it on further down the WCF pipeline.

Comment: don't forget to close MessageBuffer object after use